# objective function in optim evaluates to length 2 not 1

Tags: r

I do not even know if any of my equations are right, but I did this and its saying the objective function in optim evaluates to length 2 not 1. I am trying to estimate lambda and alfa using mle and log likelihood.

```
set.seed(1001)
q <- 1:5000
mean(q)
sd(q)

ll <- function(lambda = 0.5, alpha = 3.5) {
  n <- 5000
  (-n) * alpha * log(lambda) + 
  n * log(gamma(alpha)) - ((alpha - 1) * sum(log(q))) + 
  lambda * sum(q)
  }


MLE <- optim(c(0.5, 3.5),
  fn = ll,
  method = "L-BFGS-B",
  lower = 0.00001,
  control = list(fnscale = -1),
  hessian = T
)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several places to make your `optim` fly:

1. you should define your `ll` as a function of one argument (instead of two arguments, otherwise you will have the error "*objective function in optim evaluates to length 2 not 1*"), since within `optim`, your initial value `x0` will be pass to objective function `fn`

```
ll<-function(x){
  n<-5000
  lambda <- x[1]
  alfa <- x[2]
  (-n)*alfa*log(lambda)+n*log(gamma(alfa))-((alfa-1)*sum(log(q)))+lambda*sum(q)
}
```

- In `optim`, the dimension of lower bound `lower` should be the same as `x0`, e.g.,

```
MLE = optim(c(0.5,3.5), 
            fn = ll, 
            method = "L-BFGS-B", 
            lower = c(1e-5,1e-5), 
            control = list(fnscale = -1), 
            hessian = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i appreciate it.

Comment: Just a quick question...how do you run mle() from there

Comment: @JoyShiro What do you mean about `run mle()`? Run it as a function?

Comment: @JoyShiro What is the argument to be passed to `mle()`?

Comment: you see the equation you just helped me with... theres a follow up saying run mle() function. now for those parameters.

Comment: @JoyShiro `optim` is already a function, and `mle` is the output that saves the optimization results